# WebRTC integration in iOS With OWN Server

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, webrtc

is it possible to integrate the WebRTC concept in iOS application with out use third party API in our own server URL. 
If it is possible then tell me how we are configure the connection,by using Backend API or can we configure it from our Application itself.

Our Web team already integrated it for browser(by using Java Script) and now we are trying to integrate the concept in to iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own `signaling server` to allow clients to negotiate a call with each other. How you want to do this is up to you, but we use `node.js` for this. Our apps connect to our `node.js server` through a `TCP socket`.

When our app makes a call it sends a create signal to our `signaling server`. The server then sends a `voip push` to the callee (when a user logs in, the app registers for `voip push notifications` and sends it's `device id` to the `signaling server`). The callee connects to the server and the clients can start sending the offer and answer `SDP` and the `ICE candidates`.

This is the class we use for the `WebRTC` part of the call `<Link removed>`. You can drop those files in your project and extend a `viewcontroller` on it and implement the `delegation`. For `signaling` you will have to design your own system, but any decent programmer should be able to create a simple `signaling server`.

To add the `library` to your project I recommend [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/). Then use this to add the `library`:

```
target 'your_project_here' do
  pod 'libjingle_peerconnection'
  post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
        config.build_settings['VALID_ARCHS'] = ['armv7', 'arm64']
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Or you can follow [the guide](https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/) provided to compile the `library` yourself.

You can read more about using `WebRTC` natively [here](https://webrtc.org/native-code/native-apis/). The diagrams show the order in which you have to implement your signals. It's not that hard, when client A calls client B, basically you do:

- A creates the peerconnection factory
- A creates a peerconnection
- A creates a local media stream
- A creates an offer SDP
- A sets the offer as a local SDP
- A starts generating ICE candidates
- A sends ICE candidates to B as they come *
- A sends the offer to B *
- B creates the peerconnection factory
- B creates a peerconnection
- B sets the offer as a remote SDP
- B creates a local media stream
- B creates an answer SDP
- B sets the answer as a local SDP
- B starts generating ICE candidates
- B sends ICE candidates to A as they come *
- B sends the answer to A *
- A sets the answer as a remote SDP

* If you use the class I linked, you only have to worry about these points

Note that this class is just a starting point, it doesn't allow for multi-user calls (just 2 peers) and doesn't have much features.

Comment: Will your `BWRTCViewController` work if I want to create p2p connection between two devices in local network, without signaling server?

Comment: @SashaKid You will always need some kind of signaling, but not necessarily a signaling server. If you are on a local network you can send the SDPs and ICE candidates over a socket to a hardcoded IP-address without a server. If you want to be able to keep using the same code when your IP-addresses change you need a server though.

Comment: Thanks! Could you give some links about it? Because I haven't found it yet where the "full" steps are described. I've only found how to use `libjingle_peerconnection` and hadn't understand that signaling step is missing :-)

Comment: @SashaKid There aren't any links about it, you have to open a socket (in whatever way you prefer) and when the sendSessionDescription and sendICECandidate methods are called you send the data to the other peer. You can search online for some sources on creating sockets.

Comment: are you sure about it doesn't allow for multi-user calls (just 2 peers) and doesn't have much features. I need a multi user web chat view in my app.It should possible to share the URL up to 19 users.It means the chat contains max 20 users.

Answer (score 1):

In JS it is easier, because all the sample code is already provided by Google. While it comes to iOS, your server has to provide the signaling needed for WebRTC, as it doesn't include it. You can consider using `WebSockets/XMPP/SIPserver`. First thing I can recommend is googling the [libjingle](https://github.com/otalk/webrtc-ios) library, as it is already compiled WebRTC for all architectures.